# Multithread - Reeading from serial, draw with pyqtgraph

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to receive messages sent with different id's at 921600 baudrate from the serial port, parse these messages according to their id's and plot them in different graphs. Firstly when I plot with more than 4 id pyqtgraph I start to miss data from serial port. I was expecting this not to happen since it's a thread. Also, when I drag-drop the main window, the threads freeze and I'm missing packets again. How should I proceed here? Also here, I created a mainwindow in the code and embedded it, but what should I do if I need to create an interface with Qt designer and add more than one pyqtgraph inside it?
Here is the code

````
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
from numpy import *
import serial
import time
import threading, multiprocessing

read_data = []
cnt =0
row_count=0
currentrow= []
ser_bytes=[]
id_number = []
pkt_cnt=[]
totalpacket=0

windowWidth= 100
app = pg.mkQApp()
mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
mw.resize(1000,250)
cw = QtGui.QWidget()
mw.setCentralWidget(cw)
l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
cw.setLayout(l)

pw1 = pg.PlotWidget(name='Plot1')
curve1 = pw1.plot(clear=True,pen={'color':'m', 'cosmetic':False, 'width': 2})
l.addWidget(pw1)
Val1 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)
ptr1 = -windowWidth

pw2 = pg.PlotWidget(name='Plot2')
curve2 = pw2.plot(clear=True,pen={'color':'m', 'cosmetic':False, 'width': 2})
l.addWidget(pw2)
Val2 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)
ptr2 = -windowWidth

pw3 = pg.PlotWidget(name='Plot3')
curve3 = pw3.plot(clear=True,pen={'color':'m', 'cosmetic':False, 'width': 2})
l.addWidget(pw3)
Val3 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)
ptr3 = -windowWidth
#
pw4 = pg.PlotWidget(name='Plot4')
curve4 = pw4.plot(clear=True,pen={'color':'m', 'cosmetic':False, 'width': 2})
l.addWidget(pw4)
Val4 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)
ptr4 = -windowWidth
#
pw5 = pg.PlotWidget(name='Plot5')
curve5 = pw5.plot(clear=True,pen={'color':'m', 'cosmetic':False, 'width': 2})
l.addWidget(pw5)
Val5 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)
ptr5 = -windowWidth

pw6 = pg.PlotWidget(name='Plot6')
curve6 = pw6.plot(clear=True,pen={'color':'m', 'cosmetic':False, 'width': 2})
l.addWidget(pw6)
Val6 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)
ptr6 = -windowWidth

mw.show()

def UpdateGraphnode1(queuenode1Bytes):
    global ptr1, Val1, curve1
    if not queuenode1Bytes.empty():
        valueofgraph = queuenode1Bytes.get(timeout=5)
        Val1[:-1] = Val1[1:]
        Val1[-1] = valueofgraph
        curve1.setData(Val1)
        curve1.setPos(ptr1,0)
        ptr1+=1
        curve1.setPen('w')

def ReadBytenode1(queueArraynode1,queuenode1Bytes):
    index = 0
    if not queueArraynode1.empty():
        arrbytes = queueArraynode1.get(timeout=5)
        while index < 244:
             byteofarr = float(arrbytes[index])
             queuenode1Bytes.put(byteofarr)
             index =index + 1


def UpdateGraphnode2(queuenode2Bytes):
    global ptr2, Val2, curve2
    if not queuenode1Bytes.empty():
        valueofgraph = queuenode2Bytes.get(timeout=5)
        # print("node2", valueofgraph)
        Val2[:-1] = Val2[1:]
        Val2[-1] = valueofgraph
        curve2.setData(Val2)
        curve2.setPos(ptr2,0)
        ptr2+=1
        curve2.setPen('w')

def ReadBytenode2(queueArraynode2,queuenode2Bytes):
    index = 0
    if not queueArraynode2.empty():
        arrbytes = queueArraynode2.get(timeout=5)
        # print("len",len(arrbytes))
        while index < 244:
             byteofarr = float(arrbytes[index])
             queuenode2Bytes.put(byteofarr)
             # print("byteofarr",byteofarr)
             index =index + 1

def UpdateGraphnode3(queuenode3Bytes):
    global ptr3, Val3, curve3
    if not queuenode3Bytes.empty():
        valueofgraph = queuenode3Bytes.get(timeout=5)
        # print("node3", valueofgraph)
        Val3[:-1] = Val3[1:]
        Val3[-1] = valueofgraph
        curve3.setData(Val3)
        curve3.setPos(ptr3,0)
        ptr3+=1
        curve3.setPen('w')

def ReadBytenode3(queueArraynode3,queuenode3Bytes):
    index = 0
    if not queueArraynode3.empty():
        arrbytes = queueArraynode3.get(timeout=5)
        # print("len",len(arrbytes))
        while index < 244:
             byteofarr = float(arrbytes[index])
             queuenode3Bytes.put(byteofarr)
             # print("byteofarr",byteofarr)
             index =index + 1


def UpdateGraphnode4(queuenode4Bytes):
    global ptr4, Val4, curve4
    if not queuenode4Bytes.empty():
        valueofgraph = queuenode4Bytes.get(timeout=5)
        # print("node4",valueofgraph)
        Val4[:-1] = Val4[1:]
        Val4[-1] = valueofgraph
        curve4.setData(Val4)
        curve4.setPos(ptr4,0)
        ptr4+=1
        curve4.setPen('w')

def ReadBytenode4(queueArraynode4,queuenode4Bytes):
    index = 0
    if not queueArraynode4.empty():
        arrbytes = queueArraynode4.get(timeout=5)
        # print("len",len(arrbytes))
        while index < 244:
             byteofarr = float(arrbytes[index])
             queuenode4Bytes.put(byteofarr)
             # print("byteofarr",byteofarr)
             index =index + 1

def UpdateGraphnode5(queuenode5Bytes):
    global ptr5, Val5, curve5
    if not queuenode5Bytes.empty():
        valueofgraph = queuenode5Bytes.get(timeout=5)
        # print("node5", valueofgraph)
        Val5[:-1] = Val5[1:]
        Val5[-1] = valueofgraph
        curve5.setData(Val5)
        curve5.setPos(ptr5,0)
        ptr5+=1
        curve5.setPen('w')

def ReadBytenode5(queueArraynode5,queuenode5Bytes):
    index = 0
    if not queueArraynode5.empty():
        arrbytes = queueArraynode5.get(timeout=5)
        # print("len",len(arrbytes))
        while index < 244:
             byteofarr = float(arrbytes[index])
             queuenode5Bytes.put(byteofarr)
             # print("byteofarr",byteofarr)
             index =index + 1

def UpdateGraphnode6(queuenode6Bytes):
    global ptr6, Val6, curve6
    if not queuenode6Bytes.empty():
        valueofgraph = queuenode6Bytes.get(timeout=5)
        # print("node6", valueofgraph)
        Val6[:-1] = Val6[1:]
        Val6[-1] = valueofgraph
        curve6.setData(Val6)
        curve6.setPos(ptr6,0)
        ptr6+=1
        curve6.setPen('w')

def ReadBytenode6(queueArraynode6,queuenode6Bytes):
    index = 0
    if not queueArraynode6.empty():
        arrbytes = queueArraynode6.get(timeout=5)
        # print("len",len(arrbytes))
        while index < 244:
             byteofarr = float(arrbytes[index])
             queuenode6Bytes.put(byteofarr)
             # print("byteofarr",byteofarr)
             index =index + 1


def ReadFunction(queue):
    global ser_bytes, id_number, pkt_cnt,ser_bytes_init, totalpacket
    ser_bytes_init = ser.read_until(expected=b"\xff\xff\xff", size=244)
    totalpacket = totalpacket + 1
    id_number = ser_bytes[0:1].hex()
    pkt_cnt = ser_bytes[2]
    queue.put(ser_bytes)

    if id_number == "31":
        queueArraynode1.put(ser_bytes)
    if id_number == "32":
        queueArraynode2.put(ser_bytes)
    if id_number == "33":
        queueArraynode3.put(ser_bytes)
    if id_number == "34":
        queueArraynode4.put(ser_bytes)
    if id_number == "35":
        queueArraynode5.put(ser_bytes)
    if id_number == "36":
        queueArraynode6.put(ser_bytes)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    portName = "COM6"
    baudrate = 921600
    ser = serial.Serial(portName, baudrate,timeout = None)
    ser.flushInput()

    start = time.time()
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queueArraynode1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queueArraynode2 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queueArraynode3 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queueArraynode4 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queueArraynode5 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queueArraynode6 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queuenode1Bytes = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queuenode2Bytes = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queuenode3Bytes = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queuenode4Bytes = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queuenode5Bytes = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queuenode6Bytes = multiprocessing.Queue()
    stopped = threading.Event()


    while True:
        try:
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
            p1 = threading.Thread(target=ReadFunction, args=(queue,))
            p3 = threading.Thread(target=ReadBytenode1, args=(queueArraynode1,queuenode1Bytes,))
            p4 = threading.Thread(target=UpdateGraphnode1, args=(queuenode1Bytes,))
            p5 = threading.Thread(target=ReadBytenode2, args=(queueArraynode2, queuenode2Bytes,))
            p6 = threading.Thread(target=UpdateGraphnode2, args=(queuenode2Bytes,))
            p7 = threading.Thread(target=ReadBytenode3, args=(queueArraynode3, queuenode3Bytes,))
            p8 = threading.Thread(target=UpdateGraphnode3, args=(queuenode3Bytes,))
            p9 = threading.Thread(target=ReadBytenode4, args=(queueArraynode4, queuenode4Bytes,))
            p10 = threading.Thread(target=UpdateGraphnode4, args=(queuenode4Bytes,))
            p11 = threading.Thread(target=ReadBytenode5, args=(queueArraynode5, queuenode5Bytes,))
            p12 = threading.Thread(target=UpdateGraphnode5, args=(queuenode5Bytes,))
            p13 = threading.Thread(target=ReadBytenode6, args=(queueArraynode6, queuenode6Bytes,))
            p14 = threading.Thread(target=UpdateGraphnode6, args=(queuenode6Bytes,))

            p1.start()
            p3.start()
            p4.start()
            p5.start()
            p6.start()
            p7.start()
            p8.start()
            p9.start()
            p10.start()
            p11.start()
            p12.start()
            p13.start()
            p14.start()

            p1.join()



        except:

            print("Keyboard Interrupt")
            stop = time.time()
            break
    pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()```
````

Comment: This style of coding is completely unmanageable/unreadable due to duplication of effort. For example, if you needed to change the logic in any of the ReadBytenodeX functions, you'd have to make 6 changes. Try re-writing it as a parameter driven structure then move on to your actual issue

Answer (score 0):

@ArthurKing I edited the code again according to what you said. Here is the code:

```
            import pyqtgraph as pg
    from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
    from numpy import *
    import serial
    import time
    import threading, multiprocessing

    read_data = []
    cnt =0
    ser_bytes=[]
    id_number = []
    pkt_cnt=[]
    totalpacket=0

    windowWidth= 100
    app = pg.mkQApp()
    mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    mw.resize(1000,250)
    cw = QtGui.QWidget()
    mw.setCentralWidget(cw)
    l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    cw.setLayout(l)

    pw1 = pg.PlotWidget(name='Plot1')  ## giving the plots names allows us to link their axes together
    curve1 = pw1.plot(clear=True,pen={'color':'m', 'cosmetic':False, 'width': 2})
    l.addWidget(pw1)
    Val1 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series
    ptr1 = -windowWidth                      # set first x position

    pw2 = pg.PlotWidget(name='Plot2')  ## giving the plots names allows us to link their axes together
    curve2 = pw2.plot(clear=True,pen={'color':'m', 'cosmetic':False, 'width': 2})
    l.addWidget(pw2)
    Val2 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series
    ptr2 = -windowWidth                      # set first x position

    pw3 = pg.PlotWidget(name='Plot3')  ## giving the plots names allows us to link their axes together
    curve3 = pw3.plot(clear=True,pen={'color':'m', 'cosmetic':False, 'width': 2})
    l.addWidget(pw3)
    Val3 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series
    ptr3 = -windowWidth                      # set first x position
    #
    pw4 = pg.PlotWidget(name='Plot4')  ## giving the plots names allows us to link their axes together
    curve4 = pw4.plot(clear=True,pen={'color':'m', 'cosmetic':False, 'width': 2})
    l.addWidget(pw4)
    Val4 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series
    ptr4 = -windowWidth                      # set first x position
    #
    pw5 = pg.PlotWidget(name='Plot5')  ## giving the plots names allows us to link their axes together
    curve5 = pw5.plot(clear=True,pen={'color':'m', 'cosmetic':False, 'width': 2})
    l.addWidget(pw5)
    Val5 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series
    ptr5 = -windowWidth                      # set first x position

    pw6 = pg.PlotWidget(name='Plot6')  ## giving the plots names allows us to link their axes together
    curve6 = pw6.plot(clear=True,pen={'color':'m', 'cosmetic':False, 'width': 2})
    l.addWidget(pw6)
    Val6 = linspace(0,0,windowWidth)          # create array that will contain the relevant time series
    ptr6 = -windowWidth                      # set first x position

    mw.show()

    def UpdateGraphnode(queuenodeBytes,Val,curve,ptr):
        global ptr1, Val1, curve1
        if not queuenodeBytes.empty():
            valueofgraph = queuenodeBytes.get(timeout=5)
            # print("node1", valueofgraph)
            Val[:-1] = Val[1:]
            Val[-1] = valueofgraph
            curve.setData(Val)
            curve.setPos(ptr,0)
            ptr+=1
            curve.setPen('w')

    def ReadBytenode(queueArraynode,queuenodeBytes):
        index = 0
        if not queueArraynode.empty():
            arrbytes = queueArraynode.get(timeout=5)
            # print("len",len(arrbytes))
            while index < 244:
                 byteofarr = float(arrbytes[index])
                 queuenodeBytes.put(byteofarr)
                 # print("byteofarr",byteofarr)
                 index =index + 1


    def ReadFunction(queue):
        global ser_bytes, id_number, pkt_cnt,ser_bytes_init, totalpacket
        ser_bytes_init = ser.read_until(expected=b"\xff\xff\xff", size=244)
        totalpacket = totalpacket + 1
        id_number = ser_bytes[0:1].hex()
        pkt_cnt = ser_bytes[2]
        queue.put(ser_bytes)

        if id_number == "31":
            queueArraynode1.put(ser_bytes)
        if id_number == "32":
            queueArraynode2.put(ser_bytes)
        if id_number == "33":
            queueArraynode3.put(ser_bytes)
        if id_number == "34":
            queueArraynode4.put(ser_bytes)
        if id_number == "35":
            queueArraynode5.put(ser_bytes)
        if id_number == "36":
            queueArraynode6.put(ser_bytes)




    if __name__ == "__main__":


        portName = "COM6"
        baudrate = 921600
        ser = serial.Serial(portName, baudrate,timeout = None)
        ser.flushInput()

        start = time.time()
        queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        queueArraynode1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
        queueArraynode2 = multiprocessing.Queue()
        queueArraynode3 = multiprocessing.Queue()
        queueArraynode4 = multiprocessing.Queue()
        queueArraynode5 = multiprocessing.Queue()
        queueArraynode6 = multiprocessing.Queue()
        queuenode1Bytes = multiprocessing.Queue()
        queuenode2Bytes = multiprocessing.Queue()
        queuenode3Bytes = multiprocessing.Queue()
        queuenode4Bytes = multiprocessing.Queue()
        queuenode5Bytes = multiprocessing.Queue()
        queuenode6Bytes = multiprocessing.Queue()
        stopped = threading.Event()


        while True:
            try:
                QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
                p1 = threading.Thread(target=ReadFunction, args=(queue,))

                p3 = threading.Thread(target=ReadBytenode, args=(queueArraynode1,queuenode1Bytes,))
                p4 = threading.Thread(target=UpdateGraphnode, args=(queuenode1Bytes,Val1,curve1,ptr1,))

                p5 = threading.Thread(target=ReadBytenode, args=(queueArraynode2, queuenode2Bytes,))
                p6 = threading.Thread(target=UpdateGraphnode, args=(queuenode2Bytes,Val2,curve2,ptr2,))

                p7 = threading.Thread(target=ReadBytenode, args=(queueArraynode3, queuenode3Bytes,))
                p8 = threading.Thread(target=UpdateGraphnode, args=(queuenode3Bytes,Val3,curve3,ptr3,))

                p9 = threading.Thread(target=ReadBytenode, args=(queueArraynode4, queuenode4Bytes,))
                p10 = threading.Thread(target=UpdateGraphnode, args=(queuenode4Bytes,Val4,curve4,ptr4,))

                p11 = threading.Thread(target=ReadBytenode, args=(queueArraynode5, queuenode5Bytes,))
                p12 = threading.Thread(target=UpdateGraphnode, args=(queuenode5Bytes,Val5,curve5,ptr5,))

                p13 = threading.Thread(target=ReadBytenode, args=(queueArraynode6, queuenode6Bytes,))
                p14 = threading.Thread(target=UpdateGraphnode, args=(queuenode6Bytes,Val6,curve6,ptr6,))

                p1.start()
                p3.start()
                p4.start()
                p5.start()
                p6.start()
                p7.start()
                p8.start()
                p9.start()
                p10.start()
                p11.start()
                p12.start()
                p13.start()
                p14.start()
                p1.join()

            except:

                print("Keyboard Interrupt")
                stop = time.time()
                print("elapsed time:",stop-start)
                break
        pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```